# Cast to subclass when joining with the base class using CriteriaBuilder (OpenJPA)

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, openjpa, criteriaquery

I have a simple hierarchy `TradeCustomer` is an `OrganisationRole`. An `OrganisationRole` is linked to `Organisation`s. `Organisation` has a property `roles` containing all roles of an organisation.

I'd like to write a JPA query using the `CriteriaBuilder` which root is `Organisation` but access a property of `TradeCustomer`, e.g., I need to join `Organisation` with `OrganisationRole` and cast it to `TradeCustomer`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
CriteriaQuery<String> query = cb.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Organisation> root = query.from(Organisation.class);
Join<Organisation, TradeCustomer> tcJoin = root.join("roles");
query.select(tcJoin.get(TradeCustomer_.rate));
```

The important bit is to use the name of the column (`roles`) instead of Organisation_.roles.